# Error installing GeoServer - HTTP Status 404 - /geoserver and Application at context path /geoserver could not be started

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, ubuntu-14.04, geoserver

I've recently tried to install GeoServer with Tomcat7 on a Lubuntu 14.04 server, and had a lot of problems doing so, because Tomcat7's Java default version was set to 1.7. I've struggled a lot with this last night and I'd like to document how to fix it.

---

I installed GeoServer in my Lubuntu 14.04 machine following these steps:

**1) Install Java 8, as documented [here](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/)**

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

After that, running `java -version`returned:

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

**2) Install Tomcat 7**

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7 tomcat7-admin
```

**3) Install GeoServer's "Web Archive" version**

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.11.0/geoserver-2.11.0-war.zip
unzip geoserver-2.11.0-war.zip geoserver.war
sudo mv geoserver.war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/
sudo service tomcat7 restart
```

After that, I could not access `localhost:8080/geoserver`. Trying to do so returned the `HTTP Status 404 - /geoserver` error, with "The requested resource is not available." as a description.

Trying to deploy the `.war` file through Tomcat's `/manager` page also did not work, returning the following error: `Application at context path /geoserver could not be started`.

I've looked in the error logs to see what was going wrong, and found the following exception:

```
Apr 29, 2017 12:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerHttpSessionListenerProxy
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/geoserver/platform/GeoServerHttpSessionListenerProxy : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerHttpSessionListenerProxy)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2970)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1209)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1689)
        [...]
```

Despite what the error message says, echoing `$JAVA_HOME` returned `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`, so I was sure I had the necessary Java version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Tomcat 7 ships with 1.7 JVM as the default. This can be checked on Tomcat Web Application Manager (usually at `localhost:8080/manager`), at the bottom of the page there is a table with the JVM version.

```
+-------------------------------+---------------+-------+
|        Tomcat Version         |  JVM Version  | [...] |
+-------------------------------+---------------+-------+
| Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu) | 1.7.0_121-b00 | [...] |
+-------------------------------+---------------+-------+
```

Since GeoServer requires Java 1.8, this explains the `UnsupportedClassVersionError`. We must explicitly tell Tomcat to use JVM 1.8. This was documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24512297/2272346) and the steps are the following:

First of all we need to find where JVM 1.8 is located. Open a console terminal and enter:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

The path to Java 8's folder should be echoed back to you. In my case it's `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`. Make sure to copy it.

Then we have to edit Tomcat's configurations and tell it to use this JVM. On the console terminal, type in:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/tomcat7
```

The configuration file for Tomcat 7 should be opened. Locate the following text in it:

```
# The home directory of the Java development kit (JDK). You need at least
# JDK version 1.5. If JAVA_HOME is not set, some common directories for
# OpenJDK, the Sun JDK, and various J2SE 1.5 versions are tried.
#JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-6-jdk
```

Find the line that starts with `JAVA_HOME`, and change the path to your Java 8 folder. Make sure to uncomment the line by removing the `#` before `JAVA_HOME`. In my case, the file ended up like this:

```
# The home directory of the Java development kit (JDK). You need at least
# JDK version 1.5. If JAVA_HOME is not set, some common directories for
# OpenJDK, the Sun JDK, and various J2SE 1.5 versions are tried.
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

After that we need to restart Tomcat with the following command:

```
$ sudo service tomcat7 restart
```

Then if we check `localhost:8080/manager`, in the bottom of the page there should be something like:

```
+-------------------------------+---------------+-------+
|        Tomcat Version         |  JVM Version  | [...] |
+-------------------------------+---------------+-------+
| Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu) | 1.8.0_131-b11 | [...] |
+-------------------------------+---------------+-------+
```

And GeoServer should now be successfully started, and it should be accessible through `localhost:8080/geoserver`.